# Product of modified Bessel functions of first kind and exponential

Tags: special-functions, summation

There is a equation which goes like:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}I_n(x)e^{-x}=1$$

where $I_n(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind, and $e^{-x}$ is the exponential function. This is a well-known relation, which holds for any value of $x$.

But, when I tried to do this in *Mathematica*, it's not giving any answer.
My code goes like this:

```
Sum[BesselI[n, x]*E^(-x), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The problem is related to the fact that `Sum[BesselI[-n, x], {n, 1, ∞}]` remains unevaluated. You might consider breaking up the sum and manually plugging in the relation $I_{-n}(x)=I_n(x)$.

Comment: Using the relation mentioned by @J.M. the sum is easily evaluated using `Sum[BesselI[Abs[n], x]*Exp[-x], {n, -∞, ∞}]`.

Comment: But @Marchi , the theory dictates the value of 'n' in the modified Bessel function of first kind should range from - -∞, ∞.

Comment: @sreerajt, you are absolutely correct. However, if you look at the identity provided by J.M. effectively what is being stated is that $I_{-n}\left(x\right)=I_{n}\left(x\right)=I_{\left|n\right|}\left(x\right)$.

Comment: @Marchi to be frank enough, I can't understand that logic. My argument goes like this:
Lets analyse it numerically. Take the case of $\sum_{n=-10}^{10}\Gamma(0.2)$ where $\Gamma_n(0.2)=I_n(0.2)e^{-0.2}$. So originally, it goes like $\Gamma_0(0.2)+2[\Gamma_1(0.2)+\Gamma_2(0.2)+...+\Gamma_{10}(0.2)]$ whose numerical value is $0.826939+\textbf{2}[0.0865307]=1.0000004$ (note the '2' here). 
Now from the suggestion that u have made, the equation goes like $\Gamma_0(0.2)+[\Gamma_1(0.2)+\Gamma_2(0.2)+...+\Gamma_{10}(0.2)]$ & the ans will be 0.9134697. So that makes the difference, isn't it??

Comment: @sreerajt I'm sorry but I'm not sure I'm following your argument. I think there might be a confusion over the bounds of the sum, but again I don't know. If you look at my original comment you will see that the bounds of the summation haven't changed (-∞, ∞). If we look at your example in its full form numerically we get the following: `Sum[BesselI[n, .2] Exp[-.2], {n, -10, 10}] =  0.9999999999999998`. Similarly, if we use the specified identity: `Sum[BesselI[Abs[n], .2] Exp[-.2], {n, -10, 10}] = 0.9999999999999998`. As you can clearly see the answers are the same, as expected.

Comment: @Marchi Anyway thanks a lot for spending some time on this problem.